# Weak differentiability and continuity in one dimension

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following exercise:

> Let $u: (-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}.$ Suppose that the restrictions of $u$ to $(-1,0)$  and $(0,1)$ are both $C^1$. Show that $u$ is weakly differentiable if and only if $u$ is continuous at $0$.

It seems to me that the function $\chi_{ \{0\}}$ satisfies the above conditions, is weakly differentiable, yet is not continuous at $0$. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are mistaken. The functions are defined only up to a set of measure $0$. The example you gave does admit a continuous representative (i.e, after a suitable change on a set of measure $0$, you get a continous function), which is what is actually meant.

Comment: Thanks. I've shown that a necessary and sufficient condition is that the left and right limits of $u$ at $0$ are finite and equal, which I guess is equivalent (in this case) to $u$ having a continuous version.